# JavaScript: Avoiding duplicate Notifications

Tags: javascript, notifications

When I receive a WebSocket message, I display a Notification using `new Notification("Hello world!");` with the parsed data.

This works fine. The problem is, when I have multiple tabs open, I get notified multiple times - once for every tab open that has the script running.

I've thought of setting a cookie/LocalStorage, but that would run into a race condition. Another possibility might be to do the notifying in a Singleton, but since tabs are isolated from one another, there's no easy way to do that - or is there?

```
// This doesn't work - still getting duplicate notifications
if ($.cookie("already-notified-" + event.id) != null)
    return;

$.cookie("already-notified-" + event.id, true);
new Notification("Hello world!");
```

**How do I make sure there are no duplicate notifications?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was pretty simple after all; just not quite what I had in mind. I was very focused on a client side solution though it was (in my case) a lot simpler to go with a little trick on the server side.

What I did was store the connections in a dict with the username as key and a list of the combination of IP and port as value, a little something like this:

```
{
  "linkD": [92.135.241.187:34214, 92.135.241.187:13245, 92.135.241.187:25313],
  "amflare": [124.81.193.73:48239, 124.81.193.73:38293],
}
```

Since each new WebSocket connection is handled through a different port, I can simply append any new connections to the list and only send a notification to the most recent (last in the list) WebSocket.
On disconnect, the connection simply gets removed from the list.

Answer (score 3):

So long as it's coming from the same domain you can use [notification tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Replacing_existing_notifications) in the options object. It looks like this:

```
new Notification('Test Notification', {
  tag: 'tagname'
});
```

Technically, this does not prevent multiple notification, but rather replaces existing notifications. If you have several fire at the same time, it will look like a single notification, if they are staggered by several seconds, it may look like an extended notification, or like several. However, since the previous notifications are removed, they won't stack, and you will only have one notification when all is said and done.

Be careful using this since you may find that notifications stop occurring after the first set. If this happens, you'll need to add `renotify: true` to the option object. This occurs because the computer thinks "I have already sent a notification of *domain:stackoverflow.com-tag:tagname*, I don't need to send another." `renotify` defaults to `false`, so changing it to `true` fixes the problem.

Since you appear to be using event IDs in your code (which will change the tag), you probably won't encounter this issue, but it's good to be aware of.

Comment: great approach, but I went with a different kind of approach because I wanted exactly one Notification to be shown and... well... I had already solved the problem two months before your answer ;P thank you nonetheless.